# Is there a formula that determines the size of the leafage of a graph's spanning tree?

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory

In general terms, all the spanning trees of a graph G have the same number of leaves.

Is there any formula that allows us to know the number of leaves in terms of |V| and |E| for any spanning tree of a graph G? Assuming G is simple?

I am curious about this. Maybe something in terms of the edge-vertex ratio, or the min, max degrees in G. I know it definitely $\in O(|V|-1)$.

I was working on a proof about Minimum Spanning Trees and this question came to my mind.

Comment: Why do you say that spanning trees have the same number of leaves? If I have the complete graph $K_4$ on the vertex set $\{1,2,3,4\}$ then the spanning tree with edges $\{12,23,34\}$ has two leaves and the spanning tree with edges $\{12,13,14\}$ has three leaves.

Comment: @Lel: If a (spanning) tree $T$ has $m$ vertices $v_1,...,v_m$ of degree $\geq 3$ and all other vertices have degrees $\leq 2$, then $2 - 2 \cdot m + \sum_{\ell = 1}^m d_T(v_\ell)$ is the number of leaves. Note that $d_T(v_\ell)$ is the vertex degree of $v_\ell$ in $T$ and not in any super-graph. Does this help you?

Answer (score 1):

Both the minimum number of leaves (2 if the graph has a Hamiltonian path, otherwise larger) and the [maximum number of leaves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_dominating_set) are NP-hard to compute, making it unlikely that a simple formula for either of them exists.

Answer (score 0):

As @GordonRoyle said in comments, the statement is not true. In $K_n$ you have a star spanning tree with $n-1$ leaves and you have a path spanning tree with just 2 leaves. In fact most of the time two graph search algorithms DFS and BFS, give us two trees with different number of leaves.